# How to set the button in horizontal linearLayout with Persian language?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-button

I have to buttons in `linearLayout`. The `linearLayout` is horizontal.

My problem is when mobile language changes from English to Persian language because after that the position of buttons are swap each other.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Are you changing to any languages that are written Right-To-Left(RTL)? Like Arabic, Hebrew?

Comment: Yes i change to Persian language @Mayur Gajra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinearLayout` is not support swap childView.

You can use `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` to dynamically control the margin of this button from the top。

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you need to set `supportsRtl=false` to disable changing the layout to support RTL languages.

Like this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        >
```